# How to "build" contents of a node application to a folder called "dist"

Tags: node.js, npm, build

I have a node.js+express application. To deploy it to my server the partner is asking me to "build" the app into a folder called "dist" where all the files that need to be deployed to the server will exist. How can I implement such kind of a build.

Any hint or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't have a build process, just copy the source directory recursively :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a script which does this in your `package.json`. You simply need to create the directory and copy everything required for running your application in production to it and no more.

```
//package.json
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "mkdir -p dist && cp -R node_modules src server.js ... dist"
  }
  //...
}
```

Not the above is not cross-platform compatible. This is always the complex part of such build scripts. If this is an issue for you, I'd recommend looking at using available tooling such as [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/).

You can also use a NPM lifecycle hook to do this automatically as part of your install. Ensure you also run `npm install --production` rather than `npm install` to omit your dev dependencies.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, can you tell me what this is for? - node_modules src server.js ... dist

Comment: Example of files that might make up your express application `node_modules` your installed NPM modules. In the example `src` will probably be a directory containing your JS files and `server.js` is a common entry point for a node application, in fact `npm start` by default will automatically try and run a file named `server.js` if you have one. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start

Comment: P.S. The (...) isn't part of the command, just indicating you might need to add more files and directories to the command.